# Setting up a LaTex environment for Vim

Tags: mac, mactex, vim, vim-latex

I've always used SublimeText for writing and compiling my LaTex files, but recently I've moved the majority of my code to Vim, and I would like to do the same thing with LaTex documents. I am on OSX Sierra, with the MacTeX package, and I've tried to use [this plugin](https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview), but it gives me some errors.

My question is, how can I build a working environment for LaTex development on Vim?

Comment: http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/

Comment: MacVim works pretty well out of the box for Latex development.  I tried vim-latex but found it much too fussy and much too complicated,  so I deleted it.   Syntax high lighting just works.  For compiling I just do `<esc>!xelatex %`.  I use Skim for previewing PDF output, with the option to automatically update.  You can open Skim with `<esc>!open -a Skim %:r.pdf`.

Comment: I highly recommend https://github.com/lervag/vimtex -- much more lightweight than vim-latex, and actively maintained (based on LaTeX-Box). The documentation contains instructions to set it up to work with Skim, including forward and backward sync.

Comment: I'm currently trying vim-latex as suggested by @HenriMenke . It seems a very sound and complete plugin, I wonder if it can do a live-preview of the page like the plugin citated in my question.

Comment: Generally I think just use a PDF viewer which doesn't lock the PDF (Okular, Sumatra for example) and have that open in a window next to vim and manually compile regularly (this has always done the job for me), vim-latex has no such .  If you want help with the vim-latex-live-preview
plugin - what have you done to try and set it up and what are the errors you are receiving?

Comment: I'm starting to think that vim-latex is slowing down my Vim. When I traverse some text when editing a file the cursor disappears while I keep press i, j, k or l.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really liking the example by [@Thruston](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15036/thruston) in the comments above, so with all credit to their answer, I'd like to expand it here including installation and setup steps.

Combined with ideas from: [Dianaci's Vim Setup](http://www.dianacai.com/blog/2018/06/28/latex-vim-skim-setup/), I will outline the 5 minutes of steps it took to get my system optimal.

1. Install [Skim](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io/)
2. Open Skim and go to **Preferences > Sync** and check **"Check for file changes"** and **"Reload automatically"**
3. Install [MacTex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/) which will provide xelatex, latex, etc., if you don't already have xelatex on your system.
4. Create a VIMRC file at ~/.vimrc if you don't have one already.
5. Add the following:

Code:

```
" Mappings for compiling Latex file
autocmd FileType tex nmap <buffer> <C-T> :!xelatex %<CR>
autocmd FileType tex nmap <buffer> T :!open -a Skim %:r.pdf<CR><CR>
```

These create commands for quickly running xelatex from within VIM or MacVIM by pressing **Ctrl-T** and for opening the resulting PDF in Skim (**Shift-T**).

Once you have completed those steps, open VIM or MacVim (be sure to close and re-open if you just created your .vimrc file so that they pick up the changes).  Then open a **.tex** file and hit **Ctrl-T** to compile it to PDF.  The **xelatex** output will require you to hit return to get back to the VIM interface.  Then hit **Shift-T** to open the PDF in Skim.

Skim will update automatically from that point on whenever you hit **Ctrl-T** to recompile the **.tex** file.

Thanks to [@Thruston](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15036/thruston) from the comments above and to DianaCai for the additional VIM command ideas.  Hope you enjoy.  I certainly do.